# php preg_split() to find text inbetween two words

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

how do I use preg_split() to grab the value between [item:1] and [/item:1]
`$query= [item:1] my content [/item:1];`

This isn't working 
`$match = preg_split('/[[item:1][\/item:1]]/', $query);`
`echo $match[0];`

output should be just " my content ".

UPDATE:

```
$query = '
[page:1]you got page one content[/page:1]
[page:2]you got page two content[/page:2]
';

// parse function
function parse_page($page, $string) {

    // VERY IMPORTANT STRIP OUT ANYTHING THAT WOULD SCREW UP THE PARSE
    $string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t", "\f"), array('', ''), $string);

    // test the string with the page number
    preg_match('@\[page:'.$page.'\](.*?)\[/page:'.$page.'\]@', $string, $matches);

    // return the match if it succeeded
    if($matches) {
        return $matches;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

// if page is set then try and obtain it
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {

    // set the returned parse value to a variable
    $page_dump = parse_page(($_GET['p']), $query);

    // check to see if the match was successful
    if($page_dump[1]) {
        echo $page_dump[1];
    }else {
        echo '0';
    }
}else {

    // parse page 1, if no page specified.
    $page_dump = parse_page('1', $query);

    if($page_dump[1]) {
        echo $page_dump[1];
    }else {
        echo 'no page =(';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use preg_split(), preg_match_all() would be a better choice?

Comment: I updated it to work, but it still has a problem when you have a large dump of text in between the brackets I think its due to hidden characters such as \n for return and \t for tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to split the string, you want to capture a pattern. For that, use `preg_match`, eg

```
if (preg_match('@\[item:1\](.*?)\[/item:1\]@s', $query, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

*Edit: Tested and working*

*Edit2:* Added "s" (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php.

You should really consider a better markup solution (see XML)

Comment: I tried this and it works, but when I throw a huge dump of html in between the brackets it fails.

Comment: Is there any chance invisible characters such as \n and \t could be screwing up the regex?

Comment: @kr1zmo In that case, I'd say you're using the wrong approach. If everything must be stored in one large structure, why don't you use XML to separate your pages. That way you can use SimpleXML or DOM which should be able to handle it. Just put your HTML in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` sections

Comment: @kr1zmo Try with the "s" modifier on the pattern (see edit). This is obviously not a problem solved by regular expressions though